# Makefile cannot find include path

Tags: c++, makefile

A Makefile in the subdirectory of my project doesn't see the include path ONLY when it is used from the main Makefile of my project.  I don't have much experience with Makefiles and a lot of what I've been reading is pretty confusing.  Here is the layout of my directory (with what I have so far since I just started the project):

```
main/
    Inventory/
        Item.h
        Item.cpp
        Makefile
    tools/
        include/
            json/
                json.h
        jsoncpp.cpp
        Makefile
    main.cpp
    Makefile
```

Here is the Makefile in the main directory:

```
INCLUDE = -IInventory/
CC = g++
DEP = tools/jsoncpp.o Inventory/Item.o

Main: main.o $(DEP)
    cd tools/ && make
    cd Inventory/ && make
    $(CC) -o Main main.o $(DEP) $(INCLUDE)

main.o main.cpp
    $(CC) -c main.cpp $(INCLUDE)
```

Here is the Makefile in the tools directory:

```
INCLUDE = -Iinclude/
CC = g++

jsoncpp.o: jsoncpp.cpp
    $(CC) -c jsoncpp.cpp $(INCLUDE)
```

When I call make from the tools/, it works just fine. But when I call make from the main directory I get this error:

```
g++    -c -o tools/jsoncpp.o tools/json.cpp
tools/jsoncpp.cpp:76:23: fatal error: json/json.h: No such file or directory
#include "json/json.h"
                      ^
compilation terminated.
```

Now I partially believe that it can't find the include directory for whatever reason, but the first line in that error is fairly odd to me because of that weird gap between g++ and -c.  Since my project will soon get pretty big, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's in -I directive, it should be `#include <json/json.h>` otherwise `#include "include/json/json.h"`

EDIT: Include directory is taken from current directory, so in main/ you have to use  `-Itools/include`

Solution: Implicit rules were used so correct variable `CXXFLAGS+=$(INCLUDE)` must be set for compilation. See: [make manual](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_10.html)

And the main problem is `Main: main.o $(DEP)` - files in DEP must exist already otherwise it'll use implicit rules. Later after that cd tools/ && make is done.

Comment: That's what I have.  jsoncpp.cpp already has `#include<json/json.h>`.  That's why my `INCLUDE` only has `-Iinclude/` .

Comment: Ok, so you are in main/ compiling  tools/json.cpp and have just -Iinclude instead of -Itools/include ?

Comment: No that's in the Makefile in the tools/.  I did try to put it in the the Makefile in the main/ as well but it didn't work.

Comment: so I tried to change it to `#include <json/json.h>` with `-Itools/include` in the main directory makefile, but it is still giving me that error.

Comment: And these Makefiles are currently valid? I don't understand how: `$(CC) -c jsoncpp.cpp $(INCLUDE)` became `g++    -c -o tools/jsoncpp.o tools/json.cpp` it must be completely different action

Comment: Yes the Makefiles are valid, what I have in my original post was copy and pasted into here.  I don't know why it's doing that either. For now I just pulled the json/ out of the include/ and then compiled from main/ and it seems to work fine now.  The include folder was me attempting to be a bit more organized since I will be utilizing other tools soon.  Although I am concerned why -I and -iquote both did not work.

Comment: Well it seems like automatic rules... Try to add `CXXFLAGS+=$(INCLUDE)`. More: [link](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_10.html)

Comment: `CXXFLAGS` fixed it, thanks. EDIT: I'd give you a +1 but my rep is apparently too low.

Answer (score 0):

`#include <json/json.h>` <- preprocessor will search in all includes paths

see [gcc Include Syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html) :

> `#include <file>` This variant is used for system header files. It searches for a file named file in a standard list of system
>   directories. You can prepend directories to this list with the -I
>   option (see Invocation).
>
> `#include "file"` This variant is used for header files of your own program. It searches for a file named file first in the directory
>   containing the current file, then in the quote directories and then
>   the same directories used for . You can prepend directories to
>   the list of quote directories with the -iquote option.

Comment: This isn't some file I wrote, I downloaded this from github. [https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp]

Comment: If you call make from the main directory, you have to add `-Itools/include` so the preprocessor can find `tools/include/json/json.h` file

Comment: As stated in the comments under KIIV answer, I attempted it and it didn't work.